# Accessing AWS S3 from android app without hard-coding access keys

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS. I want to access an S3 bucket from my android app in order to upload files stored in the Downloads folder of an android device. I have tried and done that following [this](https://medium.com/@kunalpandey311997/upload-files-from-android-app-to-amazon-aws-s3-server-6d9788883b30) tutorial. However, I do not want to have the access key ID and secret access key in my source code. I found that there may be a way to do this using AWS Cognito but I haven't found a guided tutorial yet. I am also open to using other ways to access S3 as long as I don't have to hardcode the secret keys. I have also found a few questions related to this on StackOverflow but they haven't been answered well.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Hardcoding your credentials in the mobile app is not a good approach.

what I will suggest, you must request your backend server for temporary credentials.

the backend will create an STS token for S3 with limited access and give it to you.

you can find more info in the below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html

Comment: thank you for your answer. This seems to be what I want to implement. However, when I am following the steps in the link you provided, I am getting an error in the first step of Creating an AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient object. The error says: 'AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder()' has private access in 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder'. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cognito is the way to go. With an identity pool, you can send access_keys that allow you and your user to access your S3 bucket.

I know there are no clear step-by-step tutorials online, I had to figure it out myself a few weeks ago (react js and django backend).

The [official docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components) helped me well. The authentification functions are not that complicated. You can also follow [this tutorial for the aws set up process](https://medium.com/@ldarren/access-aws-s3-with-cognito-7c96fd1038f0). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of the better approach for uploading file on S3 is using presigned url. You can create an API to generate presigned url for uploading files on S3.

Visit here to find how to do it - [https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d](http://PreSigned%20URL)